# Parse web scraped data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, web-scraping

So i have this coming from my web scrape

```
pastebin.com/CMrFcBMX
```

What i'm wanting is all the prices and ticket description. Heres what i have

```
doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
       if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
         price1 = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_(?:total_price))\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         description = text.to_s.scan(/\"(ticket_desc)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         price = price1 + description
         render json: price
       end
     end
```

So this is what i have at the moment. However i'm needing to do some major edits.

Firstly i'm needing the description to ignore any plus symbols, e.g. `Later Owl + Chance For VIP Upgrade\` would need to be ignored.

Secondly I need to remove the json rendering nice, So that the first price and fees match with the first description.

Once i have this rendered i should be sorted. I'd be using this in a js file afterwards so a format like this would be best:

```
  Ticket{
    [
    Price:
    Fees:
    Description:
  ]
  }
```

Once i have it like this i should be good to finish my application ^_^

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Could you provide the source URL you scraped the XML from?

Comment: @Severin Sorry i was out yesterday, Its just a ticketmaster page :) Just search for any event where you can select the tickets :)